# Computing one column value from another, with inferred data

Tags: r, if-statement, transform, calculated-columns

I’m trying to create a function which sums actual and inferred values from one column to create another. My data is of the form:

```
Nest <- c(a,b,c,d,e,a,c,a,d,c,b)
Age <- c(5,5,4,6,5,7,6,9,10,8,10)
Brood <- c(4,3,4,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,1)
df <- data.frame(Nest, Age, Brood)
```

`Age` is in days, and `Brood` is the number of chicks in the nest at that visit. What I am trying to do is sum brood across all days up until the current age, such that 1 day with 4 chicks is worth 4, and 2 days with 3 chicks each are worth 6 etc. This requires the function to impute the values for days with no data. If a chick(s) has died between visits (i.e. there is a reduction in `Brood`), the function needs to assume they died on the middle day between visits. We can assume that the brood size on the first visit is correct for all previous days. Brood size can only decrease, not increase.

The correct output for the above data would be:

```
df$Sum.Br <- c(20,15,16,24,15,28,23,35,40,29,24)
```

As an example of how this is calculated, take `Nest C`. At the first visit, row 3, this nest was 4 days old and contained 4 chicks, therefore `Sum.Br`=4*4=16. The next time it is seen, on row 7, the chicks are 6 days old but there are only 3 left. Therefore `Sum.Br` takes the previous value (16) and adds half of the intervening days with the old number of chicks (4) and half with the new number (3), so 16 + 4 + 3 = 23. On row 10, the chicks are 8 days old (+2 days from the last visit) and there are still 3 in the nest, therefore `Sum.Br`= 23+3+3=29.

I have tried to achieve this with a series of `ifelse` commands wrapped within `transform`:

```
tmp <- transform(df, Sum.Br = ave(Brood, Nest, FUN = function(x)
                                  c(df$Age*x[1],
                                    ifelse(x[2] == x[1],
                                           df$Age*x[2],
                                           df$Age[x[1]]*x[1] + (df$Age[x[2]]-df$Age[x[1]])*((x[1]+x[2])/2)),
                                    ifelse(x[3] == x[2],
                                           ifelse(x[2]==x[1],
                                                  df$Age*x[3],
                                                  df$Age[x[1]]*x[1] + (df$Age[x[2]]-df$Age[x[1]])*((x[1]+x[2])/2) + (df$Age[[3]]-df$Age[x[2]])*x[3]),
                                           ifelse(x[2]==x[1],
                                                  df$Age[x[2]]*x[2] + (df$Age[x[3]]-df$Age[x[2]])*((x[2]+x[3])/2),
                                                  df$Age[x[1]]*x[1] + (df$Age[x[2]]-df$Age[x[1]])*((x[1]+x[2])/2) + (df$Age[x[3]]-df$Age[x[2]])*((x[2]+x[3])/2))))
```

but after 3 repeats the coding is getting long and error-prone (and I’m not even sure this is all correct!).

Can anyone see a simpler way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: You speak about days, but it's not clear what you mean - the Age column? Also, it would be easier to understand the desired functionality if you explained in an example - e.g. how is the 23 in row 7, colum "Sum.Br" calculated?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Yes, the Age column is in days. Nest C, at the first visit, was 4 days old and contained 4 chicks, therefore 4*4=16. The next time it is seen, on row 7, the chicks are 6 days old but there are only 3 left. Therefore Sum.Br takes the previous value (16) and adds half of the intervening days with the old number of chicks (4) and half with the new number (3), so 16 + 4 + 3 = 23. I'll add this to the question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other users might be interested to know that I have solved this.

I used `ddply` in the `plyr` package to split the dataframe into parts, by nest:

```
tmp <- ddply(df, "Nest", function(x){
  df2 <- data.frame(Nest = x$Nest)    # Create a dataframe with columns "Nest"
  df2$Age = x$Age                     # "Age"
  df2$Brood = x$Brood                 # and "Brood" from "df"

# The next bit is a bit long-winded, but serves the purpose
# Create an vector which contains the Sum.Brood values for each visit to that nest
# This takes the Age*Brood for the first visit, and then adds the product of the difference in age between visits and the mean brood between visits

  brood.sum = c(x$Age[1]*x$Brood[1],      
                x$Age[1]*x$Brood[1] + (x$Age[2]-x$Age[1])*((x$Brood[1]+x$Brood[2])/2),
                x$Age[1]*x$Brood[1] + (x$Age[2]-x$Age[1])*((x$Brood[1]+x$Brood[2])/2) + (x$Age[3]-x$Age[2])*((x$Brood[2]+x$Brood[3])/2),
                x$Age[1]*x$Brood[1] + (x$Age[2]-x$Age[1])*((x$Brood[1]+x$Brood[2])/2) + (x$Age[3]-x$Age[2])*((x$Brood[2]+x$Brood[3])/2) + (x$Age[4]-x$Age[3])*((x$Brood[3]+x$Brood[4])/2),
                x$Age[1]*x$Brood[1] + (x$Age[2]-x$Age[1])*((x$Brood[1]+x$Brood[2])/2) + (x$Age[3]-x$Age[2])*((x$Brood[2]+x$Brood[3])/2) + (x$Age[4]-x$Age[3])*((x$Brood[3]+x$Brood[4])/2) + (x$Age[5]-x$Age[4])*((x$Brood[4]+x$Brood[5])/2),
                x$Age[1]*x$Brood[1] + (x$Age[2]-x$Age[1])*((x$Brood[1]+x$Brood[2])/2) + (x$Age[3]-x$Age[2])*((x$Brood[2]+x$Brood[3])/2) + (x$Age[4]-x$Age[3])*((x$Brood[3]+x$Brood[4])/2) + (x$Age[5]-x$Age[4])*((x$Brood[4]+x$Brood[5])/2) + (x$Age[6]-x$Age[5])*((x$Brood[5]+x$Brood[6])/2))

# Add the non-NA elements of that vector to a new column in "df2"

  df2$bs = brood.sum[!is.na(brood.sum)]  
  df})
```

These can then be added to the original dataframe using match:

```
df$Sum.Br <- tmp$bs[match(paste(df$Nest, df$Age, sep="_"),
                          paste(tmp$Nest, tmp$Age, sep="_"))]
```